# How to create rounded rect?

Tags: p5.js, rounded-corners, rect

I'm making a basic platformer with p5.js and matter.js, but i cant get the corners to round on my player rect

```
rect(player.position.x,player.position.y,10,10,3)
```

how do i make a round rect

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you are using the most up to date version of p5.js? I can't seem to reproduce the issue in the [editor](https://editor.p5js.org/).

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  rect(50, 50, 10, 10, 3);
}
```

Gives me: [image: 10x10 box]

It may be harder to see the rounded effect because the rect is so small. If we increased the size, and increased the border `rect(50, 50, 50, 50, 10)`:

[image: 50x50 box]

The effect becomes more apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new parameter to `rect()` at the end to add smoothness of edges:

```js
rect(x, y, width, height, smoothness);
```

Example:

```js
rect(10,10,10,10,5);
```